# incorrect syntax near keyword 'end'

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

i am using C# to connect to my local database. I want to store data in a new table. I have tried this query but it gives me exception that"incorrect syntax near keyword 'end' ". 
i have searched but could not find the answer.

```
StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder();

query.Append("Create Table ");
query.Append(tableName);
query.Append(" ( ");

for (int i = 0; i < fields.Length; i++)
{
   query.Append(fields[i]);
   query.Append(" ");
   query.Append(fieldtype[i]);
   query.Append(", ");
}  

if (fields.Length > 1) { query.Length -= 2; }  //Remove trailing ", "
query.Append(");");

SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query.ToString(), myConnection);
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

[image]

Comment: Copy and paste the full error please, the image isn't as easy to work with

Comment: print out your sql and run it in SSMS.  It will likely be obvious what the problem is.

Comment: The error is not from C#. Its in your SQL Query. You need to supply your query text.

Comment: Look at the value from `query.ToString()`, that will be much easier to debug with.

Comment: Also, your `if` statement is saying, `if (fields.Length > 1)`. Wouldn't you want to remove the trailing ", ", even if there was only one field?

Comment: @icemanind: I think for that line, he meant `if (query.Length > 1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess would be that you have a field whose name is (or contains) "End" and that's confusing the parser.
 Try:

```
query.AppendFormat("[{0}] {1}, ", fields[i], fieldtype[i]);
```

Comment: it worked thanks bro. but i have another problem, my 2nd and 4th column names are identical. it is provided to me and tables are not allowed to have identical column name. so how can i change the name of only 2nd and 4th column ?

Comment: `query.AppendFormat("[{0}_{1}] {2}, ", fields[i], i, fieldtype[i]);`  That's appending the col number to each column.